# PHP, structural or OOP based language?

Tags: php, object-oriented

I would like to discuss why is PHP called a structural language? what are the OO concepts that cannot be implemented using PHP?

Comment: It's not so much about what "can be implemented using php" (it's turing complete, anything *can* be implemented in it with enough effort), but rather which principles influenced PHP's design. Of course, if we follow that to its logical conclusion, then PHP certainly isn't a structured programming language, and we'll have to coin a new category... Incompetence-based language doesn't seem like a name that's likely to catch on though....

Comment: but regardless of what PHP is, it didn't have more than the most rudimentary OOP features until PHP5. Its OOP features are overlaid on top of an old, crufty, sloppy and badly designed structural language.

Comment: @Jalf. Outstanding points given

Comment: PHP is a language?

Comment: Since PHP5.3, you can add functional. Maybe you can put an AND between theses paradigms instead of an OR ;)

Comment: @Jalf I'm sure my rep score is too low for my opinion to hold any weight, however, do you also consider C++ an incompetence-based language? There are many similarities between PHP & C++ (including additional features over time). In addition, there are a good number of things in PHP that I find much more competent than languages which get much more respect, (data manipulation, while not an OO affair, is extremely elegant & powerful in it's simplicity). It's biggest actual weakness is it's excessive flexibility (similar to JavaScript, a pure OO language). What language do you consider good?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I consider PHP language to be object-capable, not object-oriented. That's because most of the built-in constructs are not object-oriented. Take an array or a string for example. In object oriented language, you'd use it's methods to manipulate it. In fully fledged object-oriented language everything is an object.

On the other hand PHP is object-capable, you can write code, that will be OOP. Instead of using for example normal arrays, you can use data structures from [SPL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php), which actually are OOP. The only problem with that is, it's an extension, not a part of the language itself.

Comment: @vertec good analysis. I think php is also supporting with many methods to manipulate different things

Comment: I'd agree, PHP is object-capable, not object-oriented. OOP in PHP can be ignored, that to me is not the mark of an OO language.

Comment: +1 for distinguishing, in effect, "supports OOP" vs. "allows OOP".

Comment: I would be willing to bet though that as development of PHP continues they we will see PHP become more and more OOP than it currently is... +1 for "object-capable".

Answer (score 13):

Classification of programming languages is an art as most languages falls in many categories. In this case it's simple enough though. PHP is an imperative OO language, like C++. That is, you can select to use objects and classes if you like, but you don't have to.

As regards to what you can and cannot do with objects in PHP, I don't really see anything missing. But "missing" is a relative term here, as some OO languages have more features and others less. For instance, some consider language-supported properties to be a hallmark of OO, something that is lacking in both Java and PHP. Still Java is undoubtedly in the OO camp.

Judging from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Fundamental_concepts_and_features), the fundamental concepts in OO is:

- Class
- Instance
- Method
- Message passing
- Abstraction
- Encapsulation
- Inheritance
- (Subtype) polymorphism
- Decoupling

All this is part of PHP.

On a personal note, I haven't found anything in PHPs OO implementation that is lacking. There is lots of stuff in PHP that is seriously flawed, inconsistent and just weird, but that is another issue. It's OO constructs are good enough to be called complete.

Comment: @ Martin. Hundred percend agree with you.... You have analyzed in very good manner. I am also of the view that we can implement all concepts of oop in php then why some critics still dont agree to call it as oop based language

Comment: I fully second that

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [an article](http://www.optimum7.com/internet-marketing/web-development/php-objects-php-supports-objects-but-is-not-object-oriented.html) which might help to clarify this issue!

> There is a big dilemma and misunderstanding between programmers
>   regarding the object orientation of PHP. I have read a lot of forums
>   and books on this subject, and I’d like to clarify it once and for
>   all.
>
> Before actually providing my opinion, let me be really clear in
>   something; I like PHP, I am PHP Certified, and I use it every day for
>   Optimum7, a pretty innovative company that I work for as Senior
>   Programmer, and if this would help… “I always program in php thinking
>   in objects”. I can’t do it differently after programming for more than
>   9 years in C#.Net, where “everything is an object”. But once again,
>   PHP is not Object Oriented!
>
> Let’s make an analogy to clarify this.
>   We can all run, right? But, we are not all “made” for running. The
>   fact that we have the ability to run does not mean we are made for
>   that specific action. Carl Lewis (the fastest runner in his day) was
>   made to run from the beginning; he trained for it; he sacrificed
>   everything to achieve at the highest level. We all know him as “the
>   runner”. He was made for it and he developed it to the max!   What
>   about Technical Considerations?
>
> It is said that in order for a
>   programming language to be Object Oriented, it needs to support at
>   least these three basic concepts: Encapsulation, Inheritance and
>   Polymorphism. However, PHP doesn’t exactly contain a ‘full’ complement
>   of these three things, so these words don’t exactly apply to PHP like
>   they do to other languages like C# for instance.
>
> Here are just 3 of
>   the thousands of reasons that clearly illustrate that PHP is not
>   Object Oriented;
>
> 1)      It does not support casting of objects from
>   one class to another.
>   2)      It was not developed to be Object
>   Oriented i.e. thousands of functions do not belong to any object.
>   3)
>   “A new PHP” Project (Zend Framework) was created to make PHP, Object
>   Oriented.
>
> Object Oriented Programming is more than a commercial
>   phrase; it is a syntax or API Application Programming. It is a manner
>   of thinking about the problem in a more productive model. As Tom
>   Archer said: “In a truly Object Oriented language, every entity is
>   expressed through the concept of objects. The objects are the main and
>   unique idea behind the concept of Object Oriented”… As I say: Not
>   everything that appears is!
>
> Carl Lewis was made for running, not swimming.  PHP supports objects
>   but was not designed to be object-oriented.

Comment: That's not an answer. Please provide at least a small excerpt from the article (your link may go awol over time).

Comment: hmmm interesting but incredibly misleading. I fail to see how any of your 3 numbered points prove that PHP does not support Encapsulation, (creation of objects); Inheritance, (ability to create objects which inherit another's methods & properties); & Polymorphism, (ability to have objects which conform to a specific interface without dictating anything about those objects).
Finally, we KNOW that when java was younger PHP did not originally support OOP this is not speculation, however it does now. Including Encapsulation, Inheritance and Polymorphism, just call it imperative OO & be done...

Answer (score 0):

1) the first paragraph of the wikipedia-artical on structured prog langs says why

2) there are no OO concepts you cannot apply in PHP

Comment: There are no OO concepts you cannot apply in `<any language>`

Comment: I've applied OO concepts in bare-metal assembly language, using the assembler's macro abilities. So machine code is also OO. Or at least it is possible to implement objects in assembly language. Doesn't mean it's an OO language though.